# Не могу войти в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, root

я изучаю основы php,недавно для урока мне понадобилось **впервые** зайти в phpmyadmin. Зайдя через Open server в phpmyadmin мне пришлось ввести пароль и имя пользователя,но root и все остальные стандартные данные не подходят.
Может быть проблема в том,что у меня нет определённого софта на ПК?
У меня стоит только Open Server Basic версия.
Просьба изъяснять всё простым образом,ведь я только изучил **основы** php,и мне даже пока-что не особо понятно,что из себя представляет apache,или MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Логин 'root'  Пароль '*пустая строка*'
Если не вийшло то попробуй переустановить open server

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри тут  может поможет https://php-myadmin.ru/doc/ . Для новичка исользуй  xampp вот ссылка  https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html .

Comment: Извиняюсь за такое резкое начало вопроса,но всё до буквы "я" не выводится

Comment: От  А  до Я  прочитай  http://forcoder.ru/html-css/sozdaem-dinamicheskie-veb-sayty-s-pomoschyu-php-mysql-javascript-css-i-html5-1525